# jqGrid Hangs On Reload Of Data

Tags: jqgrid

I Have n jqGrid Which Loads One Line Of Data and the i have a custom button to load anotherset of data and then reload the grid ! When The Grid Loads It Works Fine No Problem But When I Add The New Data I Just Get n Loading Block I Have Been Battleing For n Few Hours And No Joy Any Help Please I Have Even Unloaded The Grid But It Does Not Recreate Even If I Reinsert The HTML Tags, Please Help ?

```html
<table id="PrimaryGrid"></table>
<input id="addinv" type="button" value="Add Custom Item">
```

```js
var string;
var Count = 0;
var myrow = [];
var item = {"id": Count,"cell": ["dfg","dfg","dfg","dfg","","false"]};
Count = Count + 1;
myrow.push(item);
$('#PrimaryGrid').jqGrid({datastr: GetJSON(),datatype: 'jsonstring',
 colNames: ['Code', 'Description', 'Qty', 'Price','Action',''],
 colModel:
  [
   { name: 'Code', index: 'Code', width: 50, align: 'left', sortable: false },
   { name: 'Description', index: 'Description', width: 300, align: 'left', sortable: false },
   { name: 'Qty', index: 'Qty', width: 50, align: 'center', sortable: false },
   { name: 'Price', index: 'Price', width: 100, align: 'right', sortable: false },
   {name:'act',index:'act', width:60,sortable:false},
   {name:'subg',index:'subg', width:1,sortable:false},
   ],
 rowNum: -1,
 height: 'auto',
 multiselect: false,
 autowidth: true,
 sortname: 'Qty',
 sortorder: 'ASC',
 viewrecords: true,
 subGrid: true,
 loadonce: false,
 gridComplete: function () { 
  for (var i = 0; i < Count; i++) {
   if($("#PrimaryGrid").getRowData(i).subg == "false"){
    $('tr#'+i, $("#PrimaryGrid"))
    .children("td.sgcollapsed")
        .html("")
        .removeClass('ui-sgcollapsed sgcollapsed');
    }
   }                    },
 caption: '<div style="width:630px;height:20px;">Items and Bills</div>'
});
function GetJSON() {
 var myarray;
 myarray = {
  "page":"1",
  "total":Count.toString(),
  "records":Count.toString(),
  "rows":myrow
 };
 return myarray;
}
$("#PrimaryGrid").jqGrid('setGridParam',{
 gridComplete: function(rowid, aData, rowelem) {
  alert('test');
  var rowData = $("#PrimaryGrid").getRowData(rowid);
  if(rowData.Action == "false"){
   $('tr#'+rowid, grid)
    .children("td.sgcollapsed")
    .html("")
    .removeClass('ui-sgcollapsed sgcollapsed');
  }
 }
});
$('.ui-jqgrid').css('font-size', '12px');
$('.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td').css('font-size', '12px'); 
document.getElementById('addinv').onclick=function(){
 var item = {"id": Count,"cell": ["dfg","dfg","dfg","dfg","","false"]};;
 Count = Count + 1;
 myrow.push(item);
 $('#PrimaryGrid').trigger("reloadGrid");
}
```

There Are 3 Errors in Firebug

b.isArray is not a function
jquery.jqGrid.min.js
Line 72
b(d.target).closest is not a function
jquery.jqGrid.min.js
Line 113
b(d.target).closest is not a function
jquery.jqGrid.min.js
Line 113

Any Help ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting a Javascript error? In FireFox, open the tools->web developer->error console then reload your page. (Assuming you have the FF plugins for this).